# Is $fp == $rbp in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

Is $fp supposed to be equal $rbp in gdb? In other words, is frame pointer (in gdb terminology) equal to base pointer (in x86 terminology)?

According to https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html,

> $fp is used for a register that contains a pointer to the current stack frame

In my C++ program they are not equal (stopped in a thread):

```
(gdb) p $fp
$12 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdae8
(gdb) p $rbp
$13 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdb20
```

gdb version is "GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12" if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is $fp == $rbp in gdb?

No, because not every processor has an `RBP` register to begin with.

Limiting discussion to `x86_64` which does, no, because GDB documentation doesn't promise such equivalency. It promises that `$fp` is an alias to the register that contains a pointer to the current stack frame.

Depending on how the code has been compiled, and where exactly it is stopped, the "equivalent" register could be `$rbp`, `$rsp`, or such register may not exist at all. In the latter case, GDB appears to "synthesize" a frame pointer to point to where the locals would be stored (if the function has any).

On machines where code is routinely compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer` (such as `x86_64`), talking about `$fp` is much less useful than talking about *actual* machine registers.